# Is there a better way to implement search map?

Tags: java, dictionary, collections

I have a map of objects `Members`

```
public class Member {

int id;
String firstName;
String lastName;
String street;
String city;
...
```

with `id` as a key, which is doing job for me and I don't want to change structure of the map.

I need to implement **search by name** functionality.
So far I can think only about 2 solutions:

1st is to iterate trough the map - not most time efficient way

2nd is to create another map with member's names as a keys and ids as values as reference to my main map and search trough this map to find the key - efficient with time but less in space, which not worry me too much

I want to ask if there is more efficient (better) way to implement search of map in my case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no point in creating a second Map if it would require 2 lookups (first find the id for a given name and then find the `Member` of that id).

It would be more efficient if the second Map would map the name keys to the `Member` values (i.e `Map<String,Member>`). You might be thinking that such an approach would require more memory compared to a `Map<String,Integer>`, but you would be wrong. A reference to a `Member` instance takes the same amount of memory as a reference to an `Integer` instance. Just because you have two `Map`s that contain the same values, doesn't mean that the `Member` instances need to be duplicated. Only the references to those isntance would be duplicated.

Comment: yes, I sometimes forgetting about how reference is working, still new to Java I think so

Answer (score 6):

You're right that iterating through the map is not the most efficient way; that will be O(n) with *n* `Members`.

You're on the right track with creating a second `Map` keyed by the members' names.  What I would change is have the `Member` references as the values for this second map too, so that you don't have to retrieve the ID then perform a second lookup on the first map to retrieve the `Member`.  This would be a `Map<String, Member>`.

Comment: but storing only 'id' takes less space than storing whole object. Ignore it, @Eran answered me to this.

Comment: Storing the `id` key requires `Integer` references but storing a `Member` requires only an object reference to the already existing `Member` object.